# How do you validate a page with AJAX content with a W3C service or similar

Tags: html, validation, jquery, w3c, standards-compliance

I have a web page that is the parent to a bunch of pages that are loaded with in using the following code.

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
  $(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://url.com/"+sourceURL+"");
}
```

To call this I would have a href like

```
href="javascript:loadContent('#content','page.php')"
```

How can you validate this using a service like the W3C markup validation service? Or for that matter grab the conent of a page in your browser. When I view source all I get is the parent regardless of what information is on the screen.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This firefox plugin uses the same algorithms to validate and has a "Validate now (HTML body after JS execution)" option:

http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/

Comment: This is old, but I've found the firefox plugin to be unsuitable for validation of XHTML pages after JS execution. It works by injecting all of the innerHTML into a temporary document and validating that. However, it fails to properly take over the doctype, applies capitalization, doesn't include the dtd, doesn't include the html xmlns attribute, doesn't include content type... It also switches to HTMLTidy for this. In short, it treats valid XHTML as invalid HTML4

Answer (score 0):

You can use W3C's [Markup Validator Web Service API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do this in Chrome Developer Tools in the Elements tab by right-clicking on the `<html>` tag and selecting **Edit as HTML**, which gives you copy-pasteable text of the current page state.

Keep in mind this doesn't include the DOCTYPE declaration, so that might need to be copied separately.